# Why the reselect createSelector necessary in this @ngrx example?

Tags: ngrx, reselect, ngrx-store

What does the following code snippet do? It is taken from this [file](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts).

`export const getCollectionLoading = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoading);`

The `fromCollection.getLoading` has only either `true` or `false` value, so can there be any optimization achieved by using the `createSelector`?

in

```
export const getCollectionLoaded = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoaded);

export const getCollectionLoading = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoading);

export const getCollectionBookIds = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getIds);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the example app's comments:

```
/**
 * Every reducer module exports selector functions, however child reducers
 * have no knowledge of the overall state tree. To make them useable, we
 * need to make new selectors that wrap them.
 **/
```

For example in reducers/collections.ts the selectors at the bottom of the file only reference the collection slice:

```
export const getLoaded = (state: State) => state.loaded;
export const getLoading = (state: State) => state.loading;
export const getIds = (state: State) => state.ids;
```

These collection selectors can't be used with state.select() because state.select expects to work with the whole AppState.  Therefore in the reducers/index.ts the selector is then wrapped with another selector so that it does work with the whole AppState:

```
export const getCollectionLoading = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoading);
```

Back to your question: why is it necessary to use reselect for this.  Reselect in this case isn't providing any optimizations.  So the main purpose of reselect is that it provides the ability to compose selectors together.

By using this composition feature we can make collections.ts only have selectors for the collections slice.  Then in index.ts we can have selectors at the AppState level.  Furthermore we can have selectors that work across different slices of the store such as this one:

```
/**
  * Some selector functions create joins across parts of state. This selector
  * composes the search result IDs to return an array of books in the store.
  */
export const getSearchResults = createSelector(getBookEntities, 
getSearchBookIds, (books, searchIds) => {
  return searchIds.map(id => books[id]);
});
```

Comment: Are the createSelector adding functionality similar to reselect, the Selector library for Redux by providing memoized Selectors?

Comment: In the code that I linked to it is using reselect.js.  I'm assuming your question is about ngrx 4 where it comes with createSelector out of the box.  Yes ngrx 4's version of createSelector provides the same memoized selector support as reselect.js: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there may be performance gains. If `fromCollection.getLoading` computation is expensive, reselect would avoid useless recalculations until `getCollectionState` keeps returning the same value.